# Calculating AR(2) model variance and mean

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, autoregressive

AR(2) model is 
$$
Y_t=2.25+0.75Y_{t-1}+0.45Y_{t-2}+e_t
$$
How can we calculate variance and mean?

Comment: There have been a few similar questions on this website earlier, have you checked them out?

Comment: You can use this resource to calculate the mean and variance of AR(p) models. It has explicit step by step derivations:
https://www.kevinsheppard.com/images/c/cf/Chapter4.pdf Then you can modify accordingly for your simpler AR(2) scenario.

Comment: The same question is answered for AR(1) models at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123796, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/337812, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245579: they show you various ways to perform these calculations.